# Set a particular bits in a byte

Tags: c

I have a binary value equivalent 1 **110** 11 i need to set the highlighted bits to 0     **101** 00 , i need a resultant value as 1 **101** 11. How to set these bits and rest still remaining the same.

Comment: have you learned about binary arithmetic? How to use `&` and `|` with masks to set/clear bits? Start there then come back with a question on where you ran into trouble.

Comment: [what have you tried? :)](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: It's called [masking bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing))

Comment: this question deserves more attention, it isn't the easiest of bit operations

Comment: @75inchpianist - I would disagree. If you have a question about setting bits, it's probably because of a school assignment.. and bit masking is a very basic operation so it should have been taught. Regardless of that, the question shows no effort as it's been asked/answered on SO several times, even a google search for the title of this question would have provided results. No effort + better versions of the same already on SO = doesn't deserve attention or upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

This should help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

If you need working example let me know but i encourage you to figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char my_byte = 0x3B; // 0b00111011

// clear the bits
my_byte &= 0xE3;

// set the bits
my_byte |= 0x14;
```

You'll find many people have many different preferences on how to write the 0xE3 and 0x14.  Some like to shift bits, however ultimately this is the code that should be produced.